# inline style is not applying in image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting html response with inline style from the service. below is the response value im getting.but that inline style is not applying.

```
<img src="IONSWeb/resources/images/SiteNew.png" ; style="position:absolute;left:590;top:160;width:100;height:80">
```

when i inspect that element in browser, it is showing below output

[image]

Comment: You are missing unit.. `px`

Comment: Also I am pretty sure that hovering over the yellow warning symbol gives you some extra information (in future cases)...

Answer (score 3):

you are missing `px`

```
<img src="IONSWeb/resources/images/SiteNew.png" style="position:absolute;left:590px;top:160px;width:100px;height:80px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing px or It may possible that some other CSS is applying to it , if you provide `!important` to your inline CSS then in will get Apply .[why !important use in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)
try like this :

```
<img src="IONSWeb/resources/images/SiteNew.png"  style="position:absolute;left:590px !important;top:160px !important;width:100px !important;height:80px !important">
```

Comment: __!important__ will fail too ;(

Comment: actually im migrating old extjs application to html5, in old application they are inline style without .px and !important. but in that application the style is applying properly. now im using that same response. for me it is not woring.  here is the style element which is working fine in old application   <img src="/IONSWeb/resources/images/SiteNew.png" ; style="position:absolute;left:150;top:160;width:100;height:80">          .style {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150;
    top: 160;
    width: 100;
    height: 80;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try using px and !important:

```
<img src="IONSWeb/resources/images/SiteNew.png" ; style="position:absolute;left:590px !important;top:160px !important;width:100px !important;height:80px !important;">
```

Comment: why are you using !important in inline css ?

Comment: Because may be the external override is using an **!important** too. So just to make sure inline css gets the highest precedence you can use **!important** inside inline Style.

Comment: actually im migrating old extjs application to html5, in old application they are inline style without .px and !important. but in that application the style is applying properly. now im using that same response. for me it is not woring. here is the style element which is working fine in old application <img src="/IONSWeb/resources/images/SiteNew.png" ; style="position:absolute;left:150;top:160;width:100;height:80"> .style { position: absolute; left: 150; top: 160; width: 100; height: 80; } –